# Self referencing OneToOne with custom where condition

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Is there a way to self reference an Entity by using a custom select and where condition?

Lets assume I have this Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Contract {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToOne
    private Contract selfContract;

}
```

For the `selfContract` I need to create a select with multiple (little complex) where conditions to get the right entity based in fields of the `contract` Entity itself. In this example the field `name` would be one where condition.

I was thinking to link the `selfContract` to a select statement in the dao class which executes as soon I need the `selfContract` (lazy). But actually not sure if this is even possible.

Comment: When you define a relationship between entities, it is that it exists previously in DB, I do not understand the question very well since a contract will always have the reference to selfContract.

If you want the selfContract entity to come initialized correctly, fetch on it, but since you don't have the relationship as Lazy you wouldn't need it.

Comment: @JLazar0 the relationship exists, but just on where conditions. So in this simple example the relation could be selfContract = where contract.name = 'Patrick'.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you would make a select on the "outer" contract where name = "some name" and then you can get the selfContract from the result.

In case you want to performance optimize it a bit then you can make a dto you select to.

Then you can select the selfContract directly where the outer contracts name = "some name"

example:

```
    @Query("SELECT new ContractDTO(c.selfContract.id, c.selfContract.name) FROM Contract c WHERE c.name = :name")
    List<ContractDTO> retrieveSelfContractsByContractNameAsDTO(@Param("name") String name);
```